# Adding a login window to a document based application

Tags: cocoa

i am creating a small document based application. In that i need to start with a login page i.e.,  when the application launches, the login page should appear first(which should not be document based).  When i am running the application right now, myDocument.xib is loaded. Is there any way by which i can load the login window first instead of the myDocument.xib?  I tried to change the MyDocument.xib to make it the login page.But then i get "Untitled" at the very first login page..  i am quite stuck at this point..pls help..i am relatively new to cocoa!

Comment: Try to be more specific with your question subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new class, add an instance of it to MainMenu.xib, connect the Application object’s `delegate` outlet to your instance, then implement the `applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:` method. Return `NO` from that method and your application will only open an untitled document when the user specifically asks for it.

As for the login window, just add a new window to MainMenu.xib and set it to be visible on launch. Place whatever logic you need for that window in your app delegate.